# Is the point on the inner border?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

There is an algorithm, it subtracts a point into a circle, an outer / inner boundary, or a figure inside the circle. But I encountered such a problem, it does not correctly display the information about the hit on the inner border of the figure that is inside the circle. For example, if you specify a coordinate (-14; 0), it will output a "point on the internal border" and if for example to specify a coordinate (0; 3), which also falls on the border, it will simply output the "point enters the region". I can not understand where I made a mistake, please tell me how to fix it?

```
if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=-14)or
   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<=round(-b/2)) or
   (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]>=round(b/2))
then t:=t+1;
if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]>r*r) then begin 
   TextOut(65, f, ' - point outside the region');
   f:=f+16;
end
   else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]=r*r) then begin 
      TextOut(65, f, ' - point on the outer boundary');
      f:=f+16; 
   end
   else if (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]>=0) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<-14) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]<round(-b/2)) or
           (x[i]*x[i]+y[i]*y[i]<=r*r) and (x[i]<=0) and (y[i]>round(b/2))
           then begin 
              TextOut(65, f, '- the point is the area');
              f:=f+16;
           end
          else if ((x[i]=0) and (y[i]<15) and (y[i]=15)) or
                  ((x[i]=-14) and (y[i]<15) and (y[i]>-15)) or
                  ((y[i]=15) and (x[i]<0) and (x[i]>-14)) or
                  ((y[i]=-15) and (x[i]<0) and (x[i]>-14))
           then begin 
                TextOut(65, f, ' - internal point');
                f:=f+16;
                end
           else begin
                TextOut(65, f, ' - dot in the inner figure');
                f:=f+16;
                end
 end;
```

Comment: I'd start with verify if-condition blocks, tried to enclose ambigous cases into `()` to ensure precedence of logic operators

Comment: Why not do some debugging?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I did not find an error when debugging

Comment: You're saying the code works (you did not find an error) when you're debugging? If it doesn't work, then I don't see how you could not find an error when debugging. At some point, an intermediate result must be incorrect.

Comment: @lurker  I do not argue, maybe I'm not looking carefully or something I do not understand, but when debugging, in my opinion everything works correctly

Comment: That makes no sense. At some point the program gives an output that you don't expect. I don't believe that you gave done any debugging.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan,  Already completely understood, this is not an algorithm problem, but the problem of the rectangle drawing function, it does not draw the OY axis, thus getting onto this axis the program and does not show that the point has got to the border, because it simply does not exist, with the algorithm everything is fine therefore debugging and did not show anything passing the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You did not show the code that draws the rectangle but I guess you use normal GDI functions. According to [MS Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162898(v=vs.85).aspx) function a rectangle does not include its right and bottom sides.

For example `Rect(-14, 15, 0, -15)` does not include the `X=0` pixels, nor the `y=-15` pixels.

See [Why are RECTs endpoint-exclusive?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040218-00/?p=40563) by Raymond Chen about reasons and consequences.

Comment: I drew it here in this way rectangle `(round (-a * 4), round (b * 2), 0, round (-b * 2));`

Comment: Is there any way to fix this so that this 0 is taken into account?

Comment: @Mr.Flatman No, except writing your own function that draws the rectangles bigger than they should be. But why would you want to do that? At least read the article, I added to my answer, first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this section is attempting to identify points on the border of the rectangle:

```
      else if ((x[i]=0) and (y[i]<15) and (y[i]=15)) or
              ((x[i]=-14) and (y[i]<15) and (y[i]>-15)) or
              ((y[i]=15) and (x[i]<0) and (x[i]>-14)) or
              ((y[i]=-15) and (x[i]<0) and (x[i]>-14))
```

I believe the first y[i]=15 should be an inequality, and that the inequalities should include equality as an option, in order to detect points on the corners of the rectangle.

```
      else if ((x[i]=0) and (y[i]<=15) and (y[i]>=-15)) or
              ((x[i]=-14) and (y[i]<=15) and (y[i]>=-15)) or
              ((y[i]=15) and (x[i]<=0) and (x[i]>=-14)) or
              ((y[i]=-15) and (x[i]<=0) and (x[i]>=-14))
```

Comment: The result is the same, when hit on the OY axis the program gives out that the point is just in the area, it does not write that it hit the border ..

Comment: @Mr.Flatman:  The sub-expression `(y[i]<15) and (y[i]=15)` can **never** be true, can it?  I thought you claimed to have debugged this?

Comment: @MartynA By the time the answer was given, it had already been corrected and verified

Comment: @Mr.Flatman:  The expression is still present in the code in your q.

Comment: Similar issue. You're using >= when you should be using > (and similar for others) in the test for the area.